# How can I run this function inside LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have function that will generate breadcrumbs format for my category e.g. `Root->Children`. It works because when I use it in my view it does work and doing its job. However I cannot cast it inside LINQ query.

Can someone explain how can I cast this particular function inside LINQ query? I've tried getting data and then setting it in `foreach` loop but it said that property is read only.

Function is `Infrastructure.CategoryHelpers.Breadcrumbs({id})` it will return `string`.

### Calling function

```
public dynamic List()
{
    var categories = _db.Categories.Select(x => new {
        ID = x.ID,
        Breadcrumbs = Infrastructure.CategoryHelpers.Breadcrumbs(x.ID, -1, ""), // this method cannot be translated into a store expression
        Name = x.Name,
        ItemCount = x.Items.Count
    });

    foreach (var c in categories)
    {
        // c.Breadcrumbs = Infrastructure.CategoryHelpers.Breadcrumbs(c.ID); // Value is read only
    }

    return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

### Error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Breadcrumbs(Int32, Int32, System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Entity Framework still doesn't support this? That's unfortunate. LINQ to SQL allows this from day one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `AsEnumerable()` which makes Linq evaluate the rest of the expression locally;

```
var categories = _db.Categories.Select(x => new { 
    ID = x.ID,                                    // This select is done in DB
    Name = x.Name,
    ItemCount = x.Items.Count
})
.AsEnumerable()                                   // Get result to LINQ to Objects                                   
.Select(x => new {                 
    ID = x.ID,                                    // This select is done in memory.
    Breadcrumbs = Infrastructure.CategoryHelpers.Breadcrumbs(x.ID, -1, ""),
    Name = x.Name,
    ItemCount = x.ItemCount
});
```

Note that you need to do all filtering (columns/Where expression/GroupBy/OrderBy) that you want done by the database *before* the `AsEnumerable()` call, since that call will fetch what is set up until then to a local IEnumerable, and do the rest of the operations on that using Linq to Objects.

Comment: Note that here the entire query becomes a linq-to-objects query, this means that you're not restricting the columns returned from the database; you're grabbing them all.  If you don't have that many more then it's fine, but if there are a lot of columns not being returned here then you'll want to pull those columns back before calling `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @Servy Agreed, also you usually want a `Where` expression to filter your fetch, that should be placed _before_  `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: If you don't actually need all of the rows, yes.

Answer (score 7):

You will simply need to avoid executing that method on the database side; get what you need from the database, convert your query to a linq-to-objects query, and then call your method.

```
var categories = _db.Categories.Select(x => new {
        ID = x.ID,
        Name = x.NameLatvian,
        ItemCount = x.Items.Count
    })//restrict the columns returned from the db
    .AsEnumerable()//Switch to Linq-to-objects
    .Select(x => new {
        x.ID,
        Breadcrumbs = Infrastructure.CategoryHelpers.Breadcrumbs(x.ID, -1, ""),
        x.Name,
        x.ItemCount,
    });
```

Comment: AsEnumerable? should be ToList()?

Comment: @CuongLe No, it most certainly should not be.  `ToList` would be wrong here; it would have a significant negative impact on performance for absolutely no gain.

Answer (score 0):

A Linq to Entities query cannot invoke a method in your application for each returned row (it cannot call Breadcrumbs).

The best answer I know of is to return x.ID and separately call Breadcrumbs() in the application layer, e.g. by using .AsEnumerable() to iterate the results in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories = from i in (from c in _db.Categories
                            select new
                            {
                                ID = c.ID,
                                Name = c.Name,
                                ItemCount = c.Items.Count
                            }).ToList()
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = i.ID,
                     Name = i.Name,
                     ItemCount = i.ItemCount,
                     Breadcrumbs = Infrastructure.CategoryHelpers.Breadcrumbs(c.ID, -1, String.Empty)
                 };
```

But please see comments below.

**Model Defined Functions**

You might also investigate [model defined functions](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef4-model-defined-functions-level-1-amp-2/) if you're using an EDMX file rather than code first.

Comment: You don't want to be calling `ToList` here, especially if there are a large number of rows returned.  It will force the entire set of data to be drawn into memory.  `AsEnumerable` will allow you to switch to linq-to-objects while still streaming the data.